# load Lua function variable via memory address?

Tags: c++, c, memory, lua, memory-address

Is it possible to load in a function variable via the memory address of the requested function?

```
aFunctionVar = loadFunc(memAddress)
if type(aFunctionVar) == 'function' then "this var is a function!" end
```

is something like loadFunc() possible in Lua?

Comment: What do you mean by a "memory address"? A C function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo the memory address of a Lua function

Comment: @lhf I'm saving the state of my program and when I try to load that state back, the only variable that is not changing back properly is a variable that holds a function, so clearly `programState[frame].myDynamicFuncVar = myDynamicFuncVar` is not working properly when I attempt to load `myDynamicFuncVar = programState[frame].myDynamicFuncVar` taking a look at these states after a load shows that this function is returning a different memory address than it was on the save. Basically I need a proper save procedure for this variable.

Comment: Since functions are dynamically allocated, saving their memory address is pointless, as it will almost definitely change from one run to another. You can serialize functions with `string.dump` then load it back with `loadstring` or `load`, but that gets rid of your upvalues.

Comment: Thanks, comparing string.dump instead of memory addresses shows that the functions aren't actually desyncing when the state is loaded. I find it strange that in the same process memory locations were changing for the same function. I wasn't opening another instance of my program when I loaded the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua functions (as with functions in most scripting languages) don't have fixed internal addresses [1]. Every time Lua executes a `function` expression, it allocates a new closure for it at some arbitrary address. The address of a function closure from some previous run is completely useless; it's virtually impossible that there is a function at that address during the current run.

Even if you do have the memory address from a function in the same process, vanilla Lua doesn't provide any way of 'loading' it, neither from inside the script nor from the C API.

If you need to serialize functions, you can use `string.dump`, which will return a string of the bytecode of the passed function, which can be loaded using `loadstring` or `load` depending on the Lua version. Note that this bytecode is independent of the source function's code; the function will do whatever it did whenever it was dumped, regardless of your changes to the source code. Also, `string.dump` cannot serialize the function's upvalues.

---

[1] Heck, even C functions might not have fixed addresses from run to run; functions in shared libraries need to be able to be placed anywhere in memory to avoid conflicts.